# Pegasus Abstractive Summary Parameter

Tags: nlp, summarization

I am playing around with the usage example from the pegasus docs. It is working fine in collab, but is using extractive summarization. Is there a way to switch this example to abstractive? The example code is:

```
from transformers import PegasusForConditionalGeneration, PegasusTokenizer
import torch
src_text = [
    """ PG&E stated it scheduled the blackouts in response to forecasts for high winds amid dry conditions. The aim is to reduce the risk of wildfires. Nearly 800 thousand customers were scheduled to be affected by the shutoffs which were expected to last through at least midday tomorrow."""
]

model_name = 'google/pegasus-xsum'
torch_device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
tokenizer = PegasusTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = PegasusForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_name).to(torch_device)
batch = tokenizer.prepare_seq2seq_batch(src_text, truncation=True, padding='longest').to(torch_device)
translated = model.generate(**batch)
tgt_text = tokenizer.batch_decode(translated, skip_special_tokens=True)
assert tgt_text[0] == "California's largest electricity provider has turned off power to hundreds of thousands of customers."
```

Thanks for the help